# jQuery - how can I stop slide up/down behaviour while clicking

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, slide

I've made a jQuery Slide up/down Nav.Menu. You can See it here:

```
<pre>[http://jsfiddle.net/mobilat/d4L0z7fa/][1]</pre>
```

The panel open/close if You click on the first 'MainNav1'. Everything is fine.

But if You'll click on MainNav1 and after it, at MainNav2 ans  ..3 .. all panels will be open.
The first panel/flyout should be closed, before another panel/flyout will be open.

I have no idea, how can I solve the problem.

Thanks for your tips/help.
    [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/mobilat/d4L0z7fa/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am resetting the slidedown class before toggling:

```
    if ($('#Slider' + index).hasClass("slideup")) {

        // .slideup any .slidedown divs
        $('.slidedown').removeClass("slidedown").addClass("slideup");

        $('#Slider' + index).removeClass("slideup").addClass("slidedown");
    } else {
        $('#Slider' + index).removeClass("slidedown").addClass("slideup");
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d4L0z7fa/10/

Answer (score -1):

I've added code to look for elements with IDs starting with "Slider" and the class "slidedown" and then made them slideup. Works nicely.

```
$( 'li.noLinkTrigger' ).each(function( index ) {

   $(this).addClass('item-' + index);

//  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );

  $( this ).click(function() {
        //$(this).addClass( "foo" );
        //e.preventDefault();
        if ($('#Slider' + index).hasClass("slideup"))
        {
            $('.slidedown').removeClass('slidedown').addClass('slideup');
            $('#Slider' + index).removeClass("slideup").addClass("slidedown");
        }
        else
        {
            $('#Slider' + index).removeClass("slidedown").addClass("slideup");
        }
  });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d4L0z7fa/11/

Comment: In your solution it's not possible to collapse the navigation if you click twice in the same element.

Comment: Fixed it. Just needed to put it inside the if statement